# Fetch blob from URL and write to file

Tags: node.js, blob, fs, fetch-api

I'm trying to `fetch` some binary data (MP3) from a server and then store it in a file:

```
var fs = require ('fs');
var fetch = require ('node-fetch');

fetch (
   audioUrl,
   {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Accept': '*/*' }
   }
)
.then ((res) => res.blob())
.then ((blob) => {
    console.log ('Blob size: ', blob.size);

    fs.writeFile (
        `filename.mp3`,
        blob,  // BUG HERE
        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log (`Error writing audio ${audioIdx}`, err);
            }
        }
    );
})
```

The problem is marked at `BUG HERE`. I'm passing a blob to `fs`, which doesn't understand blobs, and simply writes `[object Blob]`. I also tried the following:

```
blob                                // writes [object Blob]
new Uint8Array (blob)               // writes empty file
Buffer.from (new Uint8Array (blob)) // writes empty file
new Buffer (blob, 'binary')   // Error: argument is not a Buffer
```

None of the above work. How to do this correctly?

Note that I'm logging `blob.size` before calling `writeFile`. `blob.size` shows the correct size, so `fetch` seems to be successful.

Comment: which fetch library are you using?

Comment: node-fetch. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, so from the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) a Blob is not a buffer, which is what you need for writing to the file system.

I think you might be better off just getting the buffer from the response, like:

```
.then(res => res.buffer())
.then(/* write your file here */)
```

though depending on how big the files are, your best option might be to skip the `.writeFile` function altogether and pipe streams instead.

Answer (score 9):

You can stream the response to a file using `fs.createWriteStream`.

```js
fetch(
    audioUrl,
    {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Accept': '*/*' }
    }
).then(res => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const dest = fs.createWriteStream(`filename.mp3`);
        res.body.pipe(dest);
        res.body.on('end', () => resolve());
        dest.on('error', reject);
    })
});
```

Comment: This is better than `.buffer()` or `.arrayBuffer()` (at least for large files)

Answer (score 6):

Simple and working ( With the use Buffer API in nodejs )

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer 
const fs = require('fs');
fetch("https://example.com/file.mp3", {
  "headers": {},
  "method": "GET"
}).then(function(resp) {
    return resp.blob();
}).then(async function(blob) {
    var buffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
    buffer = Buffer.from(buffer)
    fs.createWriteStream('file.mp3').write(buffer);
})
```