# Download files using url in javascript

Tags: javascript, http, https, next.js, download

I have multiple url's, pointing to different files. I want to be able to download them just by using the url string automatically with Javascript code, instead of manually going to the link and downloading them.

I have searched a lot of other answers on stackoverflow, few suggest creating an anchor tag in document body, but I am doing everything on backend not creating an index.html

edit: I am using next where for an api end point I am getting post requests, each which contains URL for a file which I have to download.

This is how I expect my POST request to come:

[image]

I want to be able to do something like this (in nextjs):

```
export default async function handler (req, res) {
    if(req.method === "POST") {
       let path = "./downloads/file"
       await download(req.body.url, path)
    }
}
```

Is the `download` function possible, if so please help me with the implementation or provide any helpful packages to do the same.

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are trying to acheive here. Is the flow supposed to go: The client (e.g. browser or postman) on computer A makes an HTTP request to your Next.js API running on computer B which makes an HTTP request to another API to get a URL which computer B then uses to make another HTTP request to that URL which responds with a file that computer B saves to computer B's hard disk and then sends an HTTP response to computer A saying it was successful?

Comment: @Quentin  Computer A sends a url via a post request to the API running on Computer B, I want to be able to download the file at the location pointed by the url and save it in computer B. I guess the answer mentioning the use of `axios` below solves my query.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51444927/fetch-blob-from-url-and-write-to-file

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58642368/how-to-download-a-file-with-nodejs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use HTTP clients like **Axios**. It makes it easy to send async HTTP requests to REST endpoints and perform CRUD operations.

You can refer to the snippet below that I have used in my previous projects for file downloads. I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
const fs = require('fs')  
const Path = require('path')  
const axios = require('axios')
const crypto = require('crypto')

async function downloadFile(url) {
    const uuid = crypto.randomUUID()

    const path = Path.resolve("./utils", "uploads", uuid)
    const writer = fs.createWriteStream(path)
    
    const response = await axios({
        url,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'stream'
    })
    
    response.data.pipe(writer)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        writer.on('error', reject)
        response.data.on('end', () => {
            resolve(uuid)
        })
    })
}
```

Hope this helps, and don't forget to check out their documentation. Here is the
[link](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro).

Answer (score 0):

Download by get request

```
const downloadFabricFormat = async () => {
    try{
      await axios({
        url: '/api/fabric/fabric_excel_format/',
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'blob',
      }).then((response) => {
         const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
         const link = document.createElement('a');
         link.href = url;
         link.setAttribute('download', 'Fabric Excel Format.xlsx');
         document.body.appendChild(link);
         link.click();
      });
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  };
```

Download by post request

```
  const postFabricQRCode = async (values) => {
    try{
      await axios({
        url: `/api/qr/code/download/`,
        method: 'POST',
        responseType: 'blob',
        data: values,
      }).then((response) => {
         const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
         const link = document.createElement('a');
         link.href = url;
         link.setAttribute('download', 'fabric-qr-code.pdf');
         document.body.appendChild(link);
         link.click();
      });
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  };
```

> Change file type here. link.setAttribute('download', 'Fabric Excel Format.xlsx');
> Also manage your back-end yourself.